# unit test for django models containing "User" as ManyToManyField

Tags: django, unit-testing, django-models, manytomanyfield

So, I have a model 'Page' that has the already provided with django model, "User" as the manyToManyField like this

I think to unit test, I first create an instance of Page then assign what? err... a user to the favorite field? For this , I would have to create an instance of User ,right ? Or can I also it the other way around, create user then attach a page to pages ?

Also, my feature to test requires the user be logged in . How do I simulate or fake login in for the purpose of a unit test ?

Can you suggest how to go on about what should go in this favorite field to create an object of this kind successfully and how to have P be related to favorite to be able to conduct unit test.
Also, what unit test can I do for this ManyToManyField?

Another different question, are all foreign keys necessary to be be there for creating an object of a table for unit testing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/testing/tools/ - read this for authenticated testing.

If the ManyToMany field is on the Page model then you can assign the relationship making creating an instance of each then

```
my_page.favorite.add(my_user)
```